# Checking for undefined value, but it's still undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that I only want to run if a variable is defined and has a `length`, so I'm using this conditional block:

```
if (typeof(elem) !== undefined) {
    console.log( 'elem is not undefined' );
    console.log(typeof(elem));
    if (elem.length) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

So, how am I getting this output in the console? :

```
elem is not undefined
main.js:214 undefined
main.js:215 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: A simple way to check undefined is
`if(elem){
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer while I was typing the question and I thought I'd share it just in case someone else encounters this simple problem.

`typeof()` returns a string. If the variable is undefined, the return of `typeof()` will be the string "undefined", not the actual value using the reserved word `undefined`.

So, my code can be simplified:

```
if ((typeof(elem) != "undefined") && (elem.length)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Breaking it apart into two separate `if` statements was just my first attempt at fixing it before searching.